# How to print a 5 meter wide basemap using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, printing

I've tried using the map composer with my map extent window, but what happens is that the basemap stays the same resolution as the one that shows in my screen so it loses a whole lot of detail and the pixels look too "blocky" on a scale this large.

Is there a way to keep the basemap resolution much much higher using QGIS to obtain more detail? Or is there a better way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: what do you have your dpi set to in print composer?

Comment: the default 300dpi, and it produces a file with over 1GB... not sure if I can send it for printing

Comment: and where does your basemap come from? WMS should respect the DPI

Comment: quickmapservices